# What tools/libraries would be recommended for custom map layer (raster or vector) of dynamic shape labels?

Tags: gis

We currently have a custom raster tile layer that displays shape boundaries, and offer an experience on click/hover to show more information about the shape (name, custom attributes, etc.) based on a look-up at that coordinate. We'd like to offer a separate tile layer that can be toggled, that automatically displays the names of each shape or any other attribute.

Can anybody recommend any OSS or other solutions that can help aid in rendering text labels (instead of shape boundaries), fetched dynamically by a PostGIS geospatial boundary query?

I'm aware ArcGIS has a similar solution as part of its suite of products.

Comment: How are you currently publishing this raster tile layer? And how is the end user consuming it? It sounds like you already have a partial solution and whatever you are already using probably has the capability you need?

Answer (score 1):

[GeoServer](https://geoserver.org) is an open source server for sharing geospatial data.
Designed for interoperability, it publishes data from any major spatial data source using open standards. So, it would have no problem taking your [PostGIS data](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/database/postgis.html) and serving it out as standard WMTS tiles in raster or vector forms. [Labelling](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/index.html#styling) is handled via the standard [SLD](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/index.html) or using [CSS](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/css/index.html) or [YAML](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/ysld/index.html) if you prefer.